# How to manipulate incoming sound of skype

Tags: c#, skype, naudio

How could I get control over the incoming sound of Skype so that I could manipulate it?
Thanks to Mark Heath for his SkypeFX.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1):

Skype does provide access to the input channel. [This](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=221221) forum post will help you.

Also you may want to check these other sites:

http://skypefx.codeplex.com/

http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showforum=16

Best

Comment: Dear Vagaus,

Thanks for your answer. It would be great if you could provide a more detailed suggestion.